# Unable to Apply Linq Where Clause to Linked Entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, where-clause, iqueryable

I have a `EventEntity` which has `IEnumerable<Poc> PocEntity`.

```
public class EventEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PocEntity> Poc { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to filter `EventEntity` based on `PocEntity`. So I'm trying like this,

```
IQueryable<EventEntity> query = _context.Events.Where(x => x.Poc.Where(p => p.PocId.Equals(pocId)));
```

But I'm getting error and I'm not able to achieve this. Please assist on how to do this. I'm using EF Core.

I'm getting two errors,
Error 1:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

Error 2:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type

Comment: Please provide the error message

Comment: @rad Added Error Messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the first where condition:

```
.Where(x => x.Poc.Where(p => p.PocId.Equals(pocId)));
```

The where clause expects a `bool` expression while the only thing it gets is a collection: `p.PocId.Equals(pocId)`

**Solution**: Just add `Any()` to the end of the collection as the following:

```
.Where(x => x.Poc.Where(p => p.PocId.Equals(pocId)).Any())
```

Comment: Then how can I filter based on pocId? Please could you assist on how to refactor the query?

Comment: So now will I get Events for this Poc alone? Or this query will return All Events with this specific Poc? I'm trying to filter Events based on Poc Id so that if I pass PocId then all events related to that Poc alone needs to be listed

Comment: This statement gets you only the `Event` entity. If you want the related `Poc` to be included in the result too, you need to use `Include` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the argument to your first Where() clause is the wrong type.  `x => x.Poc.Where(p => p.PocId.Equals(pocId))` needs to evaluate to a bool.  To do this, you can use Any() instead of Where():

```
IQueryable<EventEntity> query = _context.Events.Where(x => x.Poc.Any(p => p.PocId.Equals(pocId)));
```